# JS Array.indexOf returning the wrong value

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

Now my issue is a bit of a weird one. I've got a loop going in a JS file that loops through a table element and is supposed to update an input field with values from an array.

```
var array = list.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
//9c9bd0f3-9499-4cdc-beaf-3c4d62d3b5a7, 80.0, 15334f50-43eb-46b0-8f7d-1d9011f8b3b5, 20.0
if (array.length > 1) {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    //skip first row as that's the head
    //table has 3 rows including head
        var a = table.rows[r];
        var markerId = a.getElementsByTagName("label")[1].id;
        //loop 1: 15334f50-43eb-46b0-8f7d-1d9011f8b3b5
        //loop 2: 9c9bd0f3-9499-4cdc-beaf-3c4d62d3b5a7
        var id = array.indexOf(markerId);
        //loop 1: -1
        //loop 2: 0
        a.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = Number(array[(id+1)]);  
    }
}
```

My issue is that first loop returning -1, even though the "markerId" value is in the array.

Edit 1: The list variable comes from a context.put method before the page is displayed, list = [9c9bd0f3-9499-4cdc-beaf-3c4d62d3b5a7, 80.0, 15334f50-43eb-46b0-8f7d-1d9011f8b3b5, 20.0]

Edit 2: This is the backend code that creates and sets the list values.

```
public void doEdit_assignment(RunData data) {
    SessionState state = ((JetspeedRunData) data).getPortletSessionState(((JetspeedRunData) data).getJs_peid());
    ParameterParser params = data.getParameters();
    String assignmentId = StringUtils.trimToNull(params.getString("assignmentId"));
    Assignment a = getAssignment(assignmentId, "doEdit_assignment", state);
    Set<AssignmentMarker> markers = assignmentService.getMarkers(a);
    List<String> quotas = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (AssignmentMarker marker : markers) {
        quotas.add(marker.getMarkerUserId());
        quotas.add(marker.getQuotaPercentage().toString());
        //add reassign marker select option here
    }
    state.setAttribute(ASSIGNMENT_QUOTA_VALUES, quotas);
    setAssignmentSupplementItemInState(state, a);
}
```

More than that I can't give you. The fact is that the Values are in the array, the array works on the second iteration, but for some reason not the first.

Comment: What does list or the array that's built from it look like?

Comment: @PhilCooper Added at Edit 1

Comment: It'd be best if you could provide the actual data you're working with, where is `list` defined, for instance?

Comment: @OliverRadini Edit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not provided the markup, the `table` in your code is undefined. And I am going to assume that `list` is a string, even though no quotes are present.

So,

```
var list = '[9c9bd0f3-9499-4cdc-beaf-3c4d62d3b5a7, 80.0, 15334f50-43eb-46b0-8f7d-1d9011f8b3b5, 20.0]'
var array = list.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
```

So, that means array comes out to be ..

```
[
    "9c9bd0f3-9499-4cdc-beaf-3c4d62d3b5a7",
    " 80.0",
    " 15334f50-43eb-46b0-8f7d-1d9011f8b3b5",
    " 20.0"
]
```

Your problem probably is those extra white spaces after the double quotes, so either your backend code should output the `list` without the extra spaces, like this ..

```
var list = '[9c9bd0f3-9499-4cdc-beaf-3c4d62d3b5a7,80.0,15334f50-43eb-46b0-8f7d-1d9011f8b3b5,20.0]'
// Notice, no spaces between commas.
```

Or, you should change your Javascript code to this ..

```
var array = list.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",").map(el => el.trim());
```

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) works by looping through each element of the array, and [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) removes the white spaces from the beginning/end.

Comment: Will test this now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I initially had a .replace method to remove the white spaces, but it never seemed to work. Now I went back and checked, it only replaced the first white space, never the rest.